# How to convert 1e8 value to normal integer in PHP?

Tags: php

I have integer value 4567 that I have convert it with 1e8 become 0.00004567, so my question how can I be able convert it back to 4567 in PHP ?

Comment: What do you mean by convert it with 1e8? Did you divide it by 1e8? Can't you just multiply it by the same thing to get the original thing back?

Answer (score -2):

You can convert it back using [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) e.g

using `number_format($scientific, 0, '.', '');`

```
<?php

function makeScientificNumber($number){
        $power = ($number % 10) - 1;
        return ($number / pow(10, $power)) . "e" . $power;
}

function makeNormalNumber($scientific){

    return number_format($scientific, 0, '.', '');
}

$number = 4567;
$scientific_number = makeScientificNumber($number);
echo "Scientific number is = $scientific_number";

echo PHP_EOL;

$normal_number = makeNormalNumber($scientific_number);
echo "Normal number is $normal_number";
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Scientific number is = 0.004567e6 

Normal number is 4567
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/jpUnV

Comment: sorry this my mistake 1e8 is 100000000, which is 4567/1e8 = 0.00004567 so to be able get 0.00004567 back to 4567 just use * instead of / @don't angry me